How can I Integrate a Arcgis Dashboard into a Next.js App?
I'm integrating ArcGIS into my web application built with Next.js and React, and I'm having trouble with incorporating a dashboard. Unlike the map component, I can't find a direct component for the dashboard integration. I resorted to embedding it, but I'm facing authentication issues since each iframe request (which I have in my app) needs to include a token.
First of all, i would like to know if there is any chance to use some component to display Dashboard into my page. If this is not possible, i would like to know how can i pass a token to my iframe
